# CheckCollision using javascript in Babylon JS

Tags: javascript, babylonjs

I am trying to move a sphere from top to bottom between boxes , but it goes through the boxes too.I don't know how can i use collision checker to disable that ..I have an engine,a scene,a camera , a light,a sphere,some boxes:

```js
box = BABYLON.Mesh.CreateBox("wallBox", 1, scene);
box.checkCollisions = true;
// box.setEnabled(false);

boxMaterial.diffuseColor = new BABYLON.Color3(0.25 + randomColorOffset, 0.25 + randomColorOffset, 0.25 + randomColorOffset);
box.material = boxMaterial;
box.position = new BABYLON.Vector3(-4.5 + j, -4.5 + i, -0.5);
```

and sphere:

```
var sphere = BABYLON.Mesh.CreateSphere("sphere", 6, 1, scene);
        // and we paint it green
           sphere.position = new BABYLON.Vector3(-5.5+j,-4.5+i,-0.5);
        var sphereMaterial = new BABYLON.StandardMaterial("material", scene);
        sphereMaterial.diffuseColor = new BABYLON.Color3(0,0.5,0);
          sphere.material=sphereMaterial;
```

moving sphere with WASD:

```
scene.onKeyboardObservable.add((keyInfo) => {
            switch (keyInfo.type) {
                case BABYLON.KeyboardEventTypes.KEYDOWN:
                    switch (keyInfo.event.key) {
                        case "a":
                        case "A":
                            sphere.position.x -= 0.1;
                        break;
                        case "d":
                        case "D":
                            sphere.position.x += 0.1;
                        break;
                        case "w":
                        case "W":
                            sphere.position.y += 0.1;
                        break;
                        case "s":
                        case "S":
                            sphere.position.y -= 0.1;
                        break;
                    }
                break;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want your sphere to stop when it collides with a box, you can use `sphere.moveWithCollisions(v)`
instead of changing directly the value of `sphere.position`.

In `moveWithCollisions(v)`, `v` is a `BABYLON.Vector3`, that doesn't represent the position to move to but rather the difference between the current position of the sphere and its next position.

I would go with something like that :

```js
scene.onKeyboardObservable.add((keyInfo) => {
    switch (keyInfo.type) {
        case BABYLON.KeyboardEventTypes.KEYDOWN:
            switch (keyInfo.event.key) {
                case "a":
                case "A":
                    sphere.moveWithCollisions(new BABYLON.Vector3(-0.1, 0, 0));
                break;
                case "d":
                case "D":
                    sphere.moveWithCollisions(new BABYLON.Vector3(0.1, 0, 0));
                break;
                case "w":
                case "W":
                    sphere.moveWithCollisions(new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 0.1, 0));
                break;
                case "s":
                case "S":
                    sphere.moveWithCollisions(new BABYLON.Vector3(0, -0.1, 0));
                break;
            }
        break;
    }
});
```

You can find more about it in the Babylon documentation : [Babylon - Mesh collision](https://doc.babylonjs.com/babylon101/cameras,_mesh_collisions_and_gravity#how-can-i-do-this) (part 4 - Object vs. object collision), where it's also explain how to use ellipsoids, which might help you.

Comment: It didn't help unfortunately:(, sphere is now moving up with both A&D and down with S&W

Comment: It shouldn't move in the same way, have you put -0.1 and 0.1 and not 0.1 twice ? I've tried it out on the Babylon playground with a simple example and it seems to work. You can have a look at what i did here: [Babylon Playground](https://www.babylonjs-playground.com/#0D883E#139)